# Neither the isolation level nor a strengthening of it is supported

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Using

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1)

Trying to create transaction like so:

```
OleDbConnection con;
OleDbTransaction transaction = null;
...
transaction = con.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Snapshot);
```

And get error:

> ```
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x8004D008): Neither the isolation level nor a strengthening of it is supported.
>    at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbTransaction.ProcessResults(OleDbHResult hr)
>    at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbTransaction.BeginInternal(ITransactionLocal
> ```
>
> transaction)
>          at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel
>   isolationLevel)
>          at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel
>   isolationLevel)

I made sure to run the following in the SQL Server Management Studio:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
ALTER DATABASE mydb  SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;
ALTER DATABASE mydb  SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;
ALTER DATABASE mydb  SET MULTI_USER;
```

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: If you are using SQL Server why not use the SQL Server provider instead of OLEDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace OleDb with SqlClient (as Oded suggested in a comment).

Or alternatively, execute this SQL command before beginning the transaction:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT;
```

Comment: Ended up using the sql statement, currently using OLEDB because same code supports Oracle, Sybase ASE and MSSQL.  Thanks for the help Anthony and Oded